# I'm creating a file upload in Laravel 10 with 'mimes:pdf'

Tags: php, laravel, validation, pdf, file-upload

I'm creating a file upload in Laravel 10 with 'mimes:pdf'. I've already uploaded a PDF file, but when I submit the form, an error occurs because Laravel's validator reads the uploaded file as not a PDF. However, I did upload a PDF file.

[image]
``` this is my code``laravel 10``uploadfile``pdf ```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is mostly an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 1):

**In Your Request File**

if you dont have that make first use "php artisan make:request NameFormRequest"

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048',
    ];
}
```

**In Your Controller**

```
public function uploadFile(NameFormRequest $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $path = $file->storeAs('(your path)', $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

**In file blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('route_upload_file') }}" method="post">
  @csrf
  <input type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf" required>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```